# Parallelization with openMP: shared and critical clauses

Tags: c++, openmp

Below is a portion of code parallelized via openMP. Arrays, `ap[]` and `sc[]`, are emposed to addition assignment so, I decided to make them shared and then put them in `critical` clause section since `reduction` clause does not accept arrays. But it gives a different result than its serial counterpart. Where is the problem?

```
Vector PN, Pf, Nf; // Vector is user-defined structure
Vector NNp, PPp;
Vector gradFu, gradFv, gradFw;
float dynVis_eff, SGSf; 
float Xf_U, Xf_H;
float mf_P, mf_N;
float an_diff, an_conv_P, an_conv_N, an_trans;  
float sc_cd, sc_pres, sc_trans, sc_SGS, sc_conv_P, sc_conv_N;   
float ap_trans;

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int e=0; e<nElm; ++e)
{
    ap[e] = 0.f;
    sc[e] = 0.f;
}

#pragma omp parallel for shared(ap,sc)
for (int f=0; f<nFaces; ++f)
{
    PN = cntE[face_N[f]] - cntE[face_P[f]];
    Pf = cntF[f] - cntE[face_P[f]];
    Nf = cntF[f] - cntE[face_N[f]];
    PPp = Pf - (Pf|norm(PN))*norm(PN);
    NNp = Nf - (Nf|norm(PN))*norm(PN);

    mf_P = mf[f];
    mf_N = -mf[f];

    SGSf = (1.f-ifac[f]) * SGSvis[face_P[f]]
         +      ifac[f]  * SGSvis[face_N[f]];

    dynVis_eff = dynVis + SGSf;

    an_diff = dynVis_eff * Ad[f] / mag(PN);

    an_conv_P = -neg(mf_P);
    an_conv_N = -neg(mf_N);

    an_P[f] = an_diff + an_conv_P;
    an_N[f] = an_diff + an_conv_N;

    // cross-diffusion
    sc_cd = an_diff * ( (gradVel[face_N[f]]|NNp) - (gradVel[face_P[f]]|PPp) );

    #pragma omp critical
    {       
        ap[face_P[f]] += an_N[f];   
        ap[face_N[f]] += an_P[f];

        sc[face_P[f]] += sc_cd + sc_conv_P;
        sc[face_N[f]] += -sc_cd + sc_conv_N;
    }
```

Comment: How are all your other variables declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not declared whether all the other variables in your parallel clause should be shared or not. You can do this generically with the `default` clause. If no default is specified, the variables are all shared, which is causing the problems in your code.

In your case, I'm guessing you should go for

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(none), shared(ap,sc,face_N,face_P,cntF,cntE,mf,ifac,Ad,an_P,an_N,SGSvis,dynVis), private(PN,Pf,Nf,PPp,NNp,mf_P,mf_N,SGSf,dynVis_eff,an_diff,an_conv_P,an_conv_N,sc_cd)
```

I strongly recommend always using `default(none)` so that the compiler complains every time you don't declare a variable explicitly and forces you to think about it explicitly.

Comment: I added `default(none)` just after `shared(ap,sc)` but now it gives for example, `"sc_cd" must be specified in a variable list at enclosing OpenMP parallel pragma`. There would be no problem in defining local variables at the beginning of omp clause however, it gives same error for global variables as well.

Comment: @Shibli: If you specify `default(none)` you have to explicitly declare each variable in either a `private(...)` or `shared(...)` clause.

Comment: `default(static)` is not permitted; only two choices: `shared` and `none`. Since I have a lot of private variables I am looking for something like `default(private)`.

Comment: @Shibli: Oops, forgot that `default(static)` won't work. Have amended my reply accordingly. If you're using C++, you can always try declaring the static variables inside the OMP for-loop.

Comment: @Shibli: Sorry, my bad again, mixed up `static` and `private`. Fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: There are only two shared variables. Why you declared some others also as shared? For example, why `face_N` should be shared?

Comment: @Shibli: Because you are reading from them, i.e. you are probably accessing some common data stored in them. I simply chose all the variables that you are using but not setting yourself and made them `shared`.

Comment: It worked. I just added some global variables to shared as well in your code. Thank you very much for your patience. This was really helpful!

Comment: I always have hard times looking at scientific and engineering codes with hundreds of variables explicitly declared as `shared` when the predetermined and implicit data-sharing rules from (the not so long) section 2.9.1 of the OpenMP standard match closely the natrual semantics of the parallel execution.